# Cards in bootstrap not showing border (Bootstrap 3.4.0)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Cards does not show border in bootstrap 3.4.0 version. I'm trying to have multiple cards inside a panel.

Tried include important to border and tried border-primary mb-3 and other services

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading" style="height: 30px; padding: 5px">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" style="font-size: 20px; padding: 0 20px" aria-controls="collapse4">
Features </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left:30px">
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have Cards with border.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community. With that said, please include a [mcve] to your question.  Otherwise it may be impossible to tell *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: No css is been used outside of bootstrap css

Comment: Sure, I tried to upvote both the solution as I found it valid and useful. But unfortunately,as I'm a beginner and my reputation is low,it won't be displayed publicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want a quick solution, add `.border-primary { border: 1px solid #007bff; }` to your CSS. See it in a snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="panel-heading" style="height: 30px; padding: 5px">
<h4 class="panel-title">
<a class="accordion-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="collapse"
data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false"
style="font-size: 20px; padding: 0 20px" aria-controls="collapse4">
Features </a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left:30px">
<div class="card border-primary mb-3">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
<p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to 
additional content.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="card border-primary mb-3">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
<p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to 
additional content.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<style>
  .border-primary { border: 1px solid #007bff; }
</style>
```

- Another option is to try with another bootstrap version.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. This solution helped a lot.

Comment: You're welcome @Ajith! Could you upvote my answer? (Arrow up)      And if you use it, select it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `.cards` replaced old `.panels` in bootstrap 4.x (in other words, cards do not exist in bootstrap v3.4.0)

You are mixing `.card`s and `.panel`s but you need to stick to one type of component.

Either you use only `.panel`s and bootstrap v3.4.x or you switch to `.card`s and use bootstrap v4.x (latest is preferred)

I quickly switched all `panels` to `cards` (using bootstrap v4.x) and removed inline CSS (because I don't need it for my example) and this is the result below (**see demo**)

Is that what you are looking for?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="card card-default">
  <div class="card-heading">
    <h4 class="card-title">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" style="font-size: 20px; padding: 0 20px" aria-controls="collapse4">
Features </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse4" class="card-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">
              With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
            <p class="card-text">
              With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So mean to say cards does not work properly in bootstrap 3.4.0 ?

Comment: @Ajith Correct! not only they do not work properly, Cards do not exist in bootstrap 3.4.0! you can't use it as they are non-existing (not defined) in that version